# How to calculate financial year from Date column in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

Looking to create a new column ("financial_Year") on Sheet2 in Excel file. In the new column we need to calculate the financial year using an another column "Transaction_Date", How can we perform the activity in excel.

For Eg: We have a value (12-jan-2020) in "Transaction_Date" column , First we need to convert into the date format i.e "2020-01-12" as the given date comes in the financial year "19-20" so we can append the value in "financial_Year" column.

Every financial year is between Apr to March, suppose for current date
is 06-July-2021, the Financial year would be FY 21-22

**Input data:**

```
col1   Col2           Transaction_Date  
India  AXN Ltd        12-jan-2020
UK     TIL Inc        15-Oct-2021
USA    SS Pvt Ltd     06-Mar-2019
Italy  Duke Co.       12-Dec-2020
Ger    Dell Inc       17-July-2018
```

**Expected output:**

```
col1   Col2           Transaction_Date    financial_Year
India  AXN Ltd        12-jan-2020          FY 19-20
UK     TIL Inc        15-Oct-2021          FY 21-22
USA    SS Pvt Ltd     06-Mar-2019          FY 18-19
Italy  Duke Co.       12-Dec-2020          FY 20-21
Ger    Dell Inc       17-July-2018         FY 18-19
```

What i am using is

```
="FY" & IF(MONTH(C2)<4,YEAR(C2)-1 & "-" & YEAR(C2),YEAR(C2) & "-" & YEAR(C2)+1)
```

Can we create the same using VBA?

I have tried using VBA as well

```
Dim wrkbok As Workbook
Dim wrksht As Worksheet
Dim PRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long

Set wrkbok = Workbooks.Open(strWrkbok)
Set wrksht = wrkbok.Sheets("Sheet2")

On Error Resume Next
LastRow = wrksht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = wrksht.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set PRange = wrksht.Cells(1, 1).Resize(LastRow, LastCol)

Sub InsertColumn()
        Columns("C:C").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        Range("C1").Value = "Loc"
End Sub
```

Comment: `Can we create the same using VBA. Please Suggest.` Yes, you can. But why? Especially if the formula that you have is working? And if you still want VBA then what have you tried? BTW to get `FY XX-XX` format, you need `="FY " & IF(MONTH(C2)<4,RIGHT(YEAR(C2)-1,2) & "-" & RIGHT(YEAR(C2),2),RIGHT(YEAR(C2),2) & "-" & RIGHT(YEAR(C2)+1,2))` Or `="FY " & IF(MONTH(C2)>3,RIGHT(YEAR(C2),2)&"-"&RIGHT(YEAR(C2)+1,2),RIGHT(YEAR(C2)-1,2)&"-"&RIGHT(YEAR(C2),2))`

Comment: @SiddharthRout - For the VBA Part I have used Set wrkbok = Workbooks.Open(strWrkbok)
Set wrksht = wrkbok.Sheets("Sheet2") 'select the sheet where pivot data should be taken
On Error Resume Next , LastRow = wrksht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = wrksht.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set PRange = wrksht.Cells(1, 1).Resize(LastRow, LastCol) after this dont understand how to perform using VBA

Comment: **1.** You missed the `Yes, you can. But why?` part **2.** Please update the question with the code that you tried. It is difficult to read code in comments.

Comment: @SiddharthRout -  I have updated the question , have tried up to creating a new column but don't understand how to perform the calculations

Comment: Yesterday you were doing the same thing and [wanted it to be VB.net or C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68269834/how-to-calculate-and-append-another-column-value)? So what are you actually trying to do and with what tools?

Comment: You again missed the `Yes, you can. But why?` part.

Comment: fwiw, it is much easier to do this with python. Just fyi, for a vba code the executes, user need to allow script to be run (manually) on their pc. For security reason, IT admin wouldn't normally encourage it. An excel formula doesn't have this trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method using VBA:

*assumes data starts in `A1` on the designated worksheet*
*also assumes column `C` already exists, and can be cleared*
*If that is not the case, you should insert col `C` before writing to it*

```
Option Explicit
Sub FiscalYear()
    Dim WS As Worksheet, rSrc As Range, rRes As Range
    Dim vSrc As Variant, vRes As Variant
    Dim I As Long
    Dim fyStart As Long, fyEnd As Long, tDT As Date

Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2") 'change worksheet name as appropriate

'read data into vba array for faster processing
With WS
    Set rSrc = Range(.Cells(1, 3), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp))
    vSrc = rSrc
    Set rRes = rSrc.Offset(columnoffset:=1)
End With

'Do the calculation and write results to array for faster processing
ReDim vRes(1 To UBound(vSrc, 1), 1 To 1)
vRes(1, 1) = "Financial_Year"
For I = 2 To UBound(vSrc, 1) 'skip header row
    'Fiscal year is 1-Apr => 31-Mar
    tDT = vSrc(I, 1)
    If Month(tDT) >= 4 Then
        fyStart = Year(tDT) Mod 100
    Else
        fyStart = Year(tDT) Mod 100 - 1
    End If
    
    vRes(I, 1) = Format(fyStart, """FY ""00-") & Format(fyStart + 1, "00")
Next I

'write results to the worksheet
With rRes
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .Value = vRes
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With

End Sub
```

[image]